# Could not find method implementation() for arguments [DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='com.google.firebase', name='firebase-bom', version='*

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, ionic5

I am using Ionic 5 Framework to develop an Android app and wanted to implement Firebase Could Messaging to it. After I updated two build.gradle files and Sync project with Gradle files, I got the following Error message:

**Could not find method implementation() for arguments [DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='com.google.firebase', name='firebase-bom', version='26.1.1', configuration='default'}] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.**

Here are my system information:

**Project-level build.gradle (/build.gradle):**

```
    buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

  
    project.ext {
      defaultBuildToolsVersion="29.0.2" //String
      defaultMinSdkVersion=22 //
      defaultTargetSdkVersion=29 //
      defaultCompileSdkVersion=29 //
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**App-level build.gradle (//build.gradle)**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

if (cdvHelpers.getConfigPreference('GradlePluginKotlinEnabled', 'false').toBoolean()) {
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

buildscript {
    apply from: '../CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'

    if(cdvHelpers.getConfigPreference('GradlePluginKotlinEnabled', 'false').toBoolean()) {
        String defaultGradlePluginKotlinVersion = kotlin_version

        /**
         * Fetches the user's defined Kotlin Version from config.xml.
         * If the version is not set or invalid, it will default to the ${defaultGradlePluginKotlinVersion}
         */
        String gradlePluginKotlinVersion = cdvHelpers.getConfigPreference('GradlePluginKotlinVersion', defaultGradlePluginKotlinVersion)
        if(!cdvHelpers.isVersionValid(gradlePluginKotlinVersion)) {
            println("The defined Kotlin version (${gradlePluginKotlinVersion}) does not appear to be a valid version. Falling back to version: ${defaultGradlePluginKotlinVersion}.")
            gradlePluginKotlinVersion = defaultGradlePluginKotlinVersion
        }

        // Change the version to be used.
        ext.kotlin_version = gradlePluginKotlinVersion
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        apply from: '../CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'

        implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.1')
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx'
```

**Ionic Framework Info:**

```
Ionic CLI                     : 6.7.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.3.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1000.6
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.0.6
   @angular/cli                  : 10.0.6
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : 2.4.0
   @capacitor/core : 2.4.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 9.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 12 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res                          : not installed
   native-run (update available: 1.3.0) : 1.0.0

System:

   NodeJS : v14.15.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.14.9
   OS     : Windows 10
```

**Gradle Version:**

```
Gradle 6.1.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-01-24 22:30:24 UTC
Revision:     a8c3750babb99d1894378073499d6716a1a1fa5d

Kotlin:       1.3.61
Groovy:       2.5.8
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
JVM:          1.8.0_271 (Oracle Corporation 25.271-b09)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

I have tried gradle version 6.3, 6.5, 6.7.1 and got the same kind error message.

Thanks a lot!